# What does the Express route param regex `(*)` mean?

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I cut my teeth on Perl. I'm pretty comfortable with regular expressions (but still prone to errors).

Why does `(*)` work as a regular expression in an Express route named param?

Why doesn't `(.*)` work as a regular expression in an Express route named param?

Is something like `([\\w:./]+)` a more reliable way to do it?

---

I'm trying to use a route parameter that is intended to have slashes in the value.

e.g.

If the request is:

```
http://www.example.com/new/https://www.youtube.com/trending
```

... and I'm using this route:

```
app.get('/new/:url', (req, res) => {
  console.log('new')
  console.log(req.params.url)
})
```

I want `url` to equal `https://www.youtube.com/trending`

I understand that the path is split on the slashes, so I thought I could use [a regular expression in parentheses after the named parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) to also match the slashes.

I tried `/new/:url(.*)`, which I thought should [greedily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/2948042) match anything, including the slashes, but this made the route fail completely. Why doesn't this work?

Through my own trial and error, I found that `/new/:url([\\w:./]+)` works. This makes sense to me, but seems unnecessarily complex. Is this "*the right way*"?

The one that perplexes me the most is one I found [in a YouTube video example](https://youtu.be/-pHfHa_fsUA?t=4m44s)... Why does `/new/:url(*)` work?  The `*` says 0 or more of the previous item, but there's nothing before the asterisk.

I have a feeling that the answer lies in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2495), but it's not clear to me from reading the thread exactly what's happening. Does `(*)` rely on a bug that's likely to be corrected in the next release of Express?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2495

Comment: @Adam I already read that and it either doesn't answer my question or I just don't understand. If you read my question, you'll see I made a reference to that GitHub issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first part of the question is answered by the referenced [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2495).

As for why `.*` doesn't work, the dot (`.`) isn't a special character in this implementation. It's just a dot.

From the referenced GitHub issue I understand that the asterisk (`*`) isn't understood as a quantifier at all. It just matches everything. So, that's why `(*)` works.

The part that isn't explained by the GitHub issue is `.*` which, when taking the known bug into consideration, should match a single character followed by everything else. However, through trial and error, I've determined that the `.` isn't a special character at all. In this implementation, it's just a literal dot.

For example, if the request is:

```
http://www.example.com/new/https://www.youtube.com/trending
```

... and I'm using this route:

```
app.get('/new/:url(.*)', (req, res) => {
  console.log('new')
  console.log(req.params.url)
})
```

The route wouldn't be matched, but a request for

```
http://www.example.com/new/.https://www.youtube.com/trending
```

would match (note the dot preceding the `https`) and `req.params.url` would equal `.https://www.youtube.com/trending`.

I used the following code to test:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.get('/dotStar/:dotStar(.*)', (request, response) => {
  console.log(`test request, dotStar: ${request.params.dotStar}`)
  response.send(`dotStar: ${request.params.dotStar}`)
})

app.get('/star/:star(*)', (request, response) => {
  console.log(`test request, star: ${request.params.star}`)
  response.send(`star: ${request.params.star}`)
})

app.get('/regexStar/:regexStar([a-z][a-z-]*)', (request, response) => {
  console.log(`test request, regexStar: ${request.params.regexStar}`)
  response.send(`regexStar: ${request.params.regexStar}`)
})

app.get('/dotDotPlus/:dotDotPlus(..+)', (request, response) => {
  console.log(`test request, dotDotPlus: ${request.params.regexStar}`)
  response.send(`dotDotPlus: ${request.params.dotDotPlus}`)
})

app.get('/regex/:regex([\\w:./-]+)', (request, response) => {
  console.log(`test request, regex: ${request.params.regex}`)
  response.send(`regex: ${request.params.regex}`)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`)
})
```

-- Also found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/VAggrippino/796114a27fe449fff7c45b278d9de74b)